# Android Services goes to sleep mode when app destroyed

Tags: android

sendBroadcast(intent) did not pass data when app is closed and comment out toast message, but when toast message is on inside timer, its working perfectly. Sounds funny, but need a solution how to run this service when app is destroyed.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public class BroadcastService extends Service {

    public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "com.example.broadcast_receiver";
    private CountDownTimer _Timer;

    @Override public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        _Timer = new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);
                intent.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
                BroadcastService.this.sendBroadcast(intent);
                //Toast.makeText(BroadcastService.this, millisUntilFinished/1000+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                _Timer.cancel();
            }
        }.start();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, service is started by your application in which means that it will be running on main process. Thus, upon termination of your application, the service will terminate as well.

In order to not stop the process. You may want to look into `onTaskRemoved` of your service.
From your `onTaskRemoved`, you can send broadcast to start the service again.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.ServiceStopped");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: It works perfectly and data also passing through intent  if toast message is ON in background (App Destroyed), but when i comment out toast message (Toast Off), service has stopped working :/